# Is it possible to detect the field type of a MySQL field in CakePHP?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I'm planning on converting all the datetime data from a MySQL database to the format date('d-M-Y'). I'm thinking of doing it in the afterFind() callback but I'm wondering, how do detect the field type in CakePHP so I can create conditional statements?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Aaaah, the wonders of having GetType() available...

Comment: Aaaah, the simplicity of scalar types and knowing how to handle them well… Come on @LorenVS, PHP bashing is uncalled for here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Off the top of my head: `Model::$_schema` holds the schema for the database table, including the type of the field. This is auto-populated by Cake using SQL `DESCRIBE` queries. You can go through your query results in an `afterFind()` callback and access `$this->_schema` to find out the type of the field. Try `debug($this->_schema);` to see how it's structured.

Answer (score 0):

from  http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php

```
<?php
function is_date( $str )
{
  $stamp = strtotime( $str );

  if (!is_numeric($stamp))
  {
     return FALSE;
  }
  $month = date( 'm', $stamp );
  $day   = date( 'd', $stamp );
  $year  = date( 'Y', $stamp );

  if (checkdate($month, $day, $year))
  {
     return TRUE;
  }

  return FALSE;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're after is the function getColumnType().

It's used like this:

```
$fieldType = $model->getColumnType($fieldName);
```

More info here:
[CakePHP Model::getColumnType API documentation](http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/class-Model.html#_getColumnType)